# Im getting a error when I try and compile my app

Tags: iphone, ios, file, compiler-construction

Im Getting this error: `error: /Users/*****/Dropbox/*******/iPad:iPhone/******/*****/PNGs/../******.png: No such file or directory` when I try and compile my app. Whats Wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means it can't find a file. Try deleting and reinserting the file that Xcode cannot find.

Answer (score 1):

The file path is wrong.

1. Spot the concerned file in the ressource file list of your project
2. Edit the path of the file by choosing the good file in the finder

In Xcode 4, you can edit the ressource path in the Utility view, at the right at the interface. Concerning Xcode 3, I don't remember :D

You also can delete the Reference of the file from your project, and add it again to the project.

Answer (score 1):

The directory looks like you are testing in iOS Simulator.

- Make sure the file exists.
- Check the spelling in your code.
- Perhaps just delete the file in Xcode and add it again.

Answer (score 1):

Find in project tree file name highlighted with red color, remove it from there and place correct one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the file exists first.  When you create the project make sure you are placing it in a directory somewhere in your file system.